# How to get a PHP form to verify that a date was chosen

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a mail form that will have two radios. The PHP back-end needs to make sure that one is selected. Everything works but the radio values will be either "Date 1" or "Date 2".

I've got:

```
$string_exp = ""; // what regex can I use?

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$date)) {

    $error_message .= 'You did not choose a date.<br />';

}
```

What Regular Expression can I put between the quotations to have it accept when someone chooses one of the radio options?

Comment: At least have a go at a pattern

Comment: This is probably the wrong way to do this, but without seeing your HTML form it's difficult to say.

Comment: `if (!isset_$POST['Date 1']))`?

Comment: Definitely not the best way to go about this but you may want to look at a pattern akin to `\bDate\b [12]` ([Dubuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/2N8-MaOun3CNFxOn))

Comment: I tried various patterns but I never could get it right. And thanks esqew that did the trick! That link also helps for future issues. If you'll put that as a solution I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your radios looks like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="date" value="Date 1">
<input type="radio" name="date" value="Date 2">
```

Then check like this:

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['date'])) {
     $error_message .= 'You did not choose a date.<br />';
}
```

Or like this:

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['date'] || ($_REQUEST['date'] != 'Date 1' && $_REQUEST['date'] != 'Date 2')) {
      $error_message .= 'You did not choose a date.<br />';
}
```

If your radios look like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="Date1">
<input type="radio" name="Date2">
```

Check like this:

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['Date1']) && !isset($_REQUEST['Date2'])) {
     $error_message .= 'You did not choose a date.<br />';
}
```

In this case (i.e., a selected radio with no value) the value will probably be set to "on":

```
// print_r($_REQUEST) output:
Array
(
    [Date1] => on
)
```

Though I would probably just rely on the presence of the field in $_REQUEST.

If you are just looking for a regex to test whether a string starts with the word "Date" followed by a space and an unknown integer (i.e., "Date 1", "Date 2", "Date 324") you are looking for:

```
if (preg_match('/^Date [0-9]*$/', $_REQUEST['date']) === 0) {
     $error_message .= 'You did not choose a date.<br />';
}
```

Note the use of the === operator.  This will ensure you are testing for the absense of a match, rather than an error.  See https://www.php.net/preg_match.